# What are the best ways to process continues variable and categorical variable in xgboost?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, feature-selection, xgboost

My data set has continues variable like age from 0 to 100, and the data also has categorial variable like provinces which has 50 classes. So I do not know whether I need to process the continues variable into bins. And what is the best way to process the provinces. Xgboost can not process the string type of variable. Should I use one-hot encoding for provinces with so many types?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can [factorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) your categories:

```
In [1]: prv = pd.Series(['C','A','C','B','A'], dtype='category')

In [2]: prv
Out[2]:
0    C
1    A
2    C
3    B
4    A
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [A, B, C]

In [3]: pd.factorize(prv)[0].astype(np.uint8)
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

if you want to sort your categories before factorizing them (i.e. 'A' - 0, 'B' - 1, etc.):

```
In [4]: pd.factorize(prv, sort=True)[0].astype(np.uint8)
Out[4]: array([2, 0, 2, 1, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

alternatively you can convert categories to numbers:

```
In [12]: prv.cat.rename_categories(range(prv.nunique()))
Out[12]:
0    2
1    0
2    2
3    1
4    0
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should One Hot Encode your categorical values.

XGBoost, and GBMs in general, will have difficulties with high dimensional categories.

In those case you can feed those categorical values to a pre model, then xgboost